# jquery disable next to last picture in nested list

Tags: jquery

I have an auto-generated nested list like with "up" and "down" images like this:

```
<ul id="main_ul">
  <li>Volume 1
    <ul>
       <li>down up</li>
       <li>up</li>
        <li>+ add chapter</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>+ Add Volume</li>
</ul>

when I click +add volume would like it to show:
<ul id="main_ul">
  <li>Volume 1
    <ul>
       <li>down up</li>
       <li>up</li> //correct - should not show: down up
        <li>+ add chapter</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Volume 2</li>
     <ul>
       <li>down</li>
       <li>up</li>//#total last
       <li>+ add chapter</li>
    </ul>
  <li>+ Add Volume</li>
</ul>
```

how do i remove the last "down" from every sublist. right now only removes the last of all the lists #total last

I tried this:

```
$('#main_ul li ul li .down_img:eq(-1)').hide();
```

and many others for hours but no cigar. it only removes the last "down" of the last ul. not the last down of each separate ul

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/rayse/LWWSk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#mbcp_main_ul li ul').find('li .mbcp_down_img:eq(-1)').hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Svtg8/)

Comment: when you use `#main_ul li ul li .down_img:eq(-1)` it finds all the `#main_ul li ul li .down_img` then filters the last one from it giving only one element as the result. but when you use `$('#mbcp_main_ul li ul').find('li .mbcp_down_img:eq(-1)')` it first finds all the `#mbcp_main_ul li ul` elements then in each of them it runs the filter `li .mbcp_down_img:eq(-1)` returning the last `mbcp_down_img:eq` element from each of the top element

Comment: both look the same to me. either way you have hide() in the end. so why doesn't it return only one element in this case also?

Comment: @RayS. the difference is the target set against which it is running

Comment: right but why does $('#mbcp_main_ul li ul').find('li .mbcp_down_img:eq(-1)') not return one element also? is it because #main_ul li ul li .down_img:eq(-1) is one statement only?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:eq(-1)` you can try `nth-last-child(2)` This will select second last item